# Spring Native with RestClient - RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring, jackson, native

I have created a small project using the new RestClient which is working as expected. Now I want to build it as a native image. When I run the application as native, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for swgoh.jeditempel.apicollector.boundary.rest.comlink.GuildRequest and content type "application/json"
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.writeWithMessageConverters(DefaultRestClient.java:402) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.lambda$body$0(DefaultRestClient.java:361) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchangeInternal(DefaultRestClient.java:448) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.retrieve(DefaultRestClient.java:424) ~[na:na]
    at swgoh.jeditempel.apicollector.boundary.rest.comlink.ComlinkClient.getGuild(ComlinkClient.java:55) ~[api-collector:na]
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[api-collector:na]
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[api-collector:na]
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:575) ~[api-collector:na]
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260) ~[api-collector:na]
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:616) ~[api-collector:na]
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:622) ~[api-collector:na]
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toList(ReferencePipeline.java:627) ~[api-collector:na]
    at swgoh.jeditempel.apicollector.ApiLoaderController.updateGuilds(ApiLoaderController.java:90) ~[api-collector:na]
    at swgoh.jeditempel.apicollector.ApiLoaderController.updateAll(ApiLoaderController.java:64) ~[api-collector:na]
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[api-collector:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:365) ~[api-collector:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:237) ~[api-collector:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:168) ~[api-collector:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:171) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:149) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:445) ~[api-collector:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[api-collector:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.ready(EventPublishingRunListener.java:109) ~[api-collector:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$ready$6(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:80) ~[na:na]
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[api-collector:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.ready(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:80) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:341) ~[api-collector:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342) ~[api-collector:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331) ~[api-collector:3.2.0]
    at swgoh.jeditempel.apicollector.ApiCollectorApplication.main(ApiCollectorApplication.java:10) ~[api-collector:na]
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/sa346b79c.invokeStaticInit(LambdaForm$DMH) ~[na:na]
```

The RestClient usage

```java
    @RegisterReflectionForBinding(GuildResponse.class)
    public GuildResponse getGuild(final String guildId) {
        final GuildRequest guildRequest = new GuildRequest();
        guildRequest.getPayload().setGuildId(guildId);

        return restClient.post()
                .uri(baseUrl + "/guild")
                .body(guildRequest)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .body(GuildResponse.class);
    }
```

```java
package swgoh.jeditempel.apicollector.boundary.rest.comlink;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class GuildRequest {
    private Payload payload = new Payload();

    private boolean enums = false;

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class Payload {
        private String guildId;

        private boolean includeRecentGuildActivityInfo = false;
    }
}
```

What do I miss that it works in a native build? I thought the @RegisterReflectionForBinding annotation is all I need. When I run the application with Java 21 and I can see the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter is automatically detected.